Default react state not coming back after reload
React default state not rendering
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Cook",
      day: "Feb 6th at 1:30 pm",
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Cook",
      day: "Feb 6th at 1:30 pm",
      reminder: true,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: "Cook",
      day: "Feb 6th at 1:30 pm",
      reminder: true,
    },
  ]);

  //Delete Task
  const deleteTask = (id) => {
    setTasks(tasks.filter((task) => task.id !== id));
  };

  //Toggle Reminder
  const toggleReminder = (id) => {
    setTasks(
      tasks.map((task) =>
        task.id === id ? { ...task, reminder: !task.reminder } : task
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header />
      {tasks.length === 0 ? (
        <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={deleteTask} onToggle={toggleReminder} />
      ) : (
        <p>No tasks found</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Hello guys I am trying to build a task tracker application using React by following tutorial on Youtube. I have tested out the delete function to delete tasks and after I delete all tasks and reload the page, my default tasks are not coming back. The following is in App.js using Header, Tasks and Task components.

have you tried a forced reload with CTRL + F5 ?
